# I want to print docker run environment variables inside my container

Tags: docker, shell, ubuntu, dockerfile

My docker run command :

```
docker run -e env1=value1 -e env2=value2 -e env3=value3 my_image_name(Ubuntu OS)
```

Now inside the container , I want to store these values(value1,value2 and value3) to some text file.

For that I am using `printenv > dockerenv.txt` inside my entrypoint script.

But this way I am getting all the other OS environment variables as well (ex- pwd,hostname etc) along with value1,value2 and value3.

I want to store only those environment variables that are passed by docker run command.

Note : -  I am not sure how my varibales are going to get passed to my docker run command. It is dynamic. There could be n numbers of environment variables

Comment: why don't `echo env1=$env1 >> dockerenv.txt; echo env2=$env2 >> dockerenv.txt; echo env3=$env3 >> dockerenv.txt` ?

Comment: I am not sure how my varibales are going to get passed to my docker run command. It is dynamic. There could be n numbers of environment variables

Comment: Why don't you use a naming rule ? Try to force all needed variable to begin with `APPNAME_`, and use a regex to filter that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to store only those environment variables that are passed by docker run command.

From inside the container, there's no way to differentiate between "environment variables set via the `docker run` command line" and "other environment variables". The only thing you could consider is using a specific prefix on variables you're setting via `docker run`:

```
docker run -e prefix_env1=val1 -e prefix_env2=val2 ...
```

Then inside the container you can use `printenv | grep '^prefix_'` to match only those variables.